# Microsoft Access Nullable Int display zero if value is null, how to display blank

Tags: ms-access, nullable, preventdefault

I have a nullable int column in my access. I know this may be trivial but I am trying to find a way to show NULL value as blank. Somehow it just defaults to zero so basically all NULL value are being equated to null which is not my intention. For example my column is use for sorting. So if the user did not set a value in the sort column it should remain NULL and not zero.

Note: using access-2007

Comment: Where are you seeing these results?  In the table viewer itself?  In a query, form, or report?

Comment: In the display view of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Nz(column, "")
```

Additional details:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx

Otherwise, you need to trace through your entire data path - from your table, to any query that is being used, to the form.  If this is truly a nullable column with null values, something, somewhere is defaulting it to a 0.  (Check the table.  If there is a query behind the form, check the query without the form, etc.)

Comment: I actaully tried that already (I added equal sign before Nz). It results to zero still.

Comment: @Nassign - please reply to my comment on the original question for additional assistance.

Comment: I got it. I was using a nullable bit instead of an int on an SQL backend and linked it to the access database. somehow a nullable bit wont set to empty string.